# Cómo ingresar valores a un campo vacío de una tabla con datos

Tags: mysql

estoy trabajando con MySQL Workbench 8 y he importado datos a una tabla "alumnos" que contiene los campos: nombre, a_paterno, a_materno son aproximadamente 300 registros, agregué un campo nuevo: cod_alumno en el que quiero ingresar valores, tengo el siguiente prodecimiento:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS agregacodigo;
CREATE PROCEDURE agregacodigo()
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE num_registros INT;

    SET i = 1;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_registros FROM alumnos;

    WHILE i<=num_registros DO
        SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
        UPDATE alumnos SET cod_alumno = i LIMIT i,i;
        SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

El código me genera un error porque el UPDATE no acepta el offset, alguna alternativa? gracias.

Comment: y porque queres un offset en ese lugar?

Comment: La idea que tengo es ir al primer registro a ingresar el valor 1, luego moverme al segundo registro e ingresar el valor 2, asi sucesivamente.

Comment: para que version de mysql, desde 8 en adelante hay rownum

Comment: tengo el 8.0.20 y el 5.7.10

Comment: esas versiones de que son?

Comment: Mysql, estoy revisando para el rownum, y es exactamente lo que buscaba. Para versiones tiene algun equivalente?